# SQL VBA - Delete from where not exist

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Access database that I am trying to insert, update and delete with SQL commands using VBA from an Excel workbook. My update and insert commands work fine but my delete command freezes Excel. I have tried various methods with and without table aliasing.

```
    Set dbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'New ADODB.Connection
    dbConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=C:\Users\me\Desktop\Opstats Import\TG_DB.accdb;"
    
    Set dbCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 'New ADODB.Command
    
L = "[Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "].[LImport$]"
    
    With dbCommand
        .ActiveConnection = dbConnection
        
        'Update Labour

        SQL = "UPDATE tblLabour A" & _
              " INNER JOIN " & L & " X" & _
              " ON A.PositionID = X.PositionID AND A.Date = X.Date AND A.PayCode = X.PayCode" & _
              " SET A.Hours = X.Hours, A.Dollars = X.Dollars"
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Execute

        SQL = "DELETE FROM tblLabour" & _
              " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM " & L & " X WHERE X.PositionID = tblLabour.PositionID AND X.Date = tblLabour.Date AND X.PayCode = tblLabour.PayCode)"
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Execute

        'Insert Labour

        SQL = "INSERT INTO tblLabour" & _
              " SELECT * FROM " & L & " X" & _
              " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT PositionID, Date, PayCode FROM tblLabour A WHERE A.PositionID = X.PositionID AND A.Date = X.Date AND A.PayCode = X.PayCode)"
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Execute

    End With
    
    dbConnection.Close
    
    Set dbCommand = Nothing
    Set dbConnection = Nothing
```

I have also tried:

```
        SQL = "DELETE A FROM tblLabour A" & _
              " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM " & L & " X WHERE X.PositionID = A.PositionID AND X.Date = A.Date AND X.PayCode = A.PayCode)"
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Execute
```

Because of my data source, I do not have a primary key and rely on three fields to create a composite primary key so the only way to find records is to match all three fields.

I tested the SQL in an Access query and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating fields to use as a unique identifier with NOT IN().

```
SQL = "DELETE FROM tblLabour" & _
       " WHERE NOT PositionID & PayCode & [Date] IN (SELECT PositionID & PayCode & [Date] FROM " & L & " X)"
```